# Is there a Python click function, internal or external, that gets the name of an option?

Tags: python, python-click

I've written several extensions for `click`, but I fear my function to get the name of an option may miss something. Is there any internal or external function predefined by `click` itself to get the name when passed an option?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use `ctx.params` which returns a list of Parameters, and each parameter has a `.name` parameter ?
[Click documentation](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/?highlight=context#click.Command.params)

This gets the name of the first parameter

```py
print(ctx.command.get_params(ctx)[0].name)
```

Comment: I couldn't find the `.name` method anywhere; could you link there specifically?

Comment: Not even sure if it's in the docs, but running the code works. It's not a method though, my bad, you just call `.name` to access the parameter